# Angular Spectator, cannot use custom matchers

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-spectator, spectator

I am trying to use [spectator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/spectator) to test my Angular components.
I want to use one of the custom matchers but I get the error `Property 'toBeEmpty' does not exist on type 'JestMatchersShape<Matchers<void, Element>, Matchers<Promise<void>, Element>>'`.

The component is really simple and this is the simple test:

```
  import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
  import { Spectator, createComponentFactory } from '@ngneat/spectator';

  import { imports } from '../../shared.module';

  import { InputComponent } from './input.component';

  describe('InputComponent', () => {
    let spectator: Spectator<InputComponent>;
    const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
      component: InputComponent,
      imports: imports,
    });

    describe('label', () => {
      it('should not show when not passed', () => {
        spectator = createComponent({
          props: {
            control: new FormControl(),
          },
        });

        const matLabel = spectator.query('mat-label');

        expect(matLabel).toBeEmpty(); // <-- Error here
      });
    });
  });
```

I read spectator's documentation and didn't say anything about import the custom matchers, also the examples in internet they don't mention about anything to do before using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue.

I tried to import the custom matchers like this:

```
   import { toBeEqual } from '@ngneat/spectator';
```

But I was getting the same error. Reading other answers about mocking the Angular Router with `spectator`
I noticed an import:

```
   import '@ngneat/spectator/jest';
```

I didn't find instructions about it in order to use the custom matchers.

Anyway, it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem recently and found an explanation on this page: [Jest Support](https://ngneat.github.io/spectator/docs/jest-support/).

Instead of:

```
import '@ngneat/spectator/jest';
```

you can just change the default import to include `/jest` at end.

If you have something like:

```
import { SpectatorPipe, createPipeFactory } from '@ngneat/spectator';
```

change it to:

```
import { SpectatorPipe, createPipeFactory } from '@ngneat/spectator/jest';
```